# Checkbox and controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, controller

I have one Model Having two virtual Properties i.e

> public virtual IEnumerable MediumIds { get; set; }
>      public virtual IEnumerable AnsLanguageIds { get; set; }

I have Used ViewBag To Populate Them i.e

> ViewBag.MediumIds = db.ExamMediums.Where(x => x.ExamId == _ExamId).Select(x => x.Medium);
>     ViewBag.AnsLanguageIds = new SelectList(db.AnswerLanguages.ToList(), "AnswerLanguageId", "AnsLanguage");

And My View Is

> @foreach (var item in
>                   ViewBag.MediumIds)
>                           {

```
               <input id="MediumIds" name="MediumIds" value="@item.MediumId" type="checkbox"  /><strong>
                            @item.Medium1 </strong>

                        @Html.DropDownList("AnsLanguageIds")
                        <br />
                    }
```

I want The functionality like when the checkbox is selected than only the the dropdown should be enabled else it should be disabled and also i want that for which medium which anslanguage is selected

Your answer will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the drop down lists disabled by default by passing `new { disabled = "disabled" }` as the `DropDownList()` method's `htmlAttributes` argument. This JQuery should toggle the select's disabled state when each checkbox is checked:

```
$(function() {
    $("input#MediumIds").click(function() {
        var checkbox = $(this);
        var dropDownlist = checkbox.sibling("select:first");
        dropDownlist.attr("disabled", checkbox.is(":checked") ? "" : "disabled");
    });
});
```

...I'm not sure what you mean by "i want that for which medium which anslanguage is selected"?